# Find the DIV which has most <p> using Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to use Simple HTML DOM parser (PHP) for a project. Basically, I have a source code of a webpage like this-

```
<html>
...
...
<div id="1> Some content here</div>
<div id="2> Some content here</div>
<div id="3> Some content here</div>
<div id="4> Some content here</div>
....
...
</html>
```

Some of this div contains paragraphs `(<p>)`, now I want print the paragraph of the div which has most of the `<p>` tag inside it. This is my first time using HTML parser and I have tried many things but nothing is giving me appropriate output.
EDIT- A div may have some parent div. So I want to print the text of the div which contains most `<p>`. For below example I want the ouput of div id 4 only :

```
<html>
...
...
<div id="1> <p> Hey</p></div>
<div id="2> <p> Hey there!</p></div>
<div id="3> 
    <p> How are you<p>
    <div id="4">
         <p> Hey</p>
         <p> How are you</p>
    </div>
</div>

....
...
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $html = file_get_html('http://your_web_page');

    $arr = array();
    // Find all divs, but you should include the parent class
    foreach($html->find('.parent_class_name div') as $key => $element) {
           echo $key." : ".count($element->find('p')) . '<br>';
           $arr[$key] = count($element->find('p'));
   }
print_r(max($arr));
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know parent class name beforehand. Basically, I am putting a URL of a news article and I want to fetch only article text. So I thought maybe find the div with most `<p>` tag will give me the answer. Is there any other way to find this?

Comment: there is always a way, can you provide us the url of the page ? to be able to see the entire html dom.

Answer (score 0):

Do this (run the snippet and click the button to get the result):

```js
$("#clickMe").on('click', function()
{
   var mostP = 0;
   var textOfMostP = '';
   
   // iterate through all divs on page
   $( "div" ).each(function() 
   {
      // check the count of childern p elements inside current div
      if($(this).children("p").length > mostP)
      {
          textOfMostP = this.innerHTML;
          mostP = $(this).children("p").length;
      }
   });
   
   // If a result for most p's has been found
   if(mostP != 0)
   {
      $( "#result" ).html("Result:<br/>Number of p's: " + mostP + "<br/><br/>The text:" + textOfMostP);
   }
});
```

```css
div
{
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #09f;
  border-radius:4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>this is some text</p>
  <p>this is some more</p>
  <p>this is even more</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>there is only this here</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>two lines are here</p>
  <p>this is second line</p>
</div>

<input type="button" id="clickMe" value="Write div with most <p>s" />

<div id="result">The result will come here</div>
```